# Jquery post submission still goes to the php page not showing the message on the original page

Tags: jquery-post

I've tried to read similar postings. Couldn't get a clue on my code about why mine is still going to the php page displaying messages and not showing on the original html page.

Here is the code snippet.

```
In javascript 

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#myForm").submit(function(){
    var url = $(this).attr("action"); 
    var str=$(this).serialize();
    $.post(url,str,function(msg){$('msg_div').show();$('msg_div').html(msg);});
    return false;
  });
});

in html
<form name="myForm" action="abc.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
...
<input type="submit" name="Submit" id="Submit" value="Submit" onClick="return validateForm()"/>

in PHP
if (mail($to, $subject, $msg, $headers))    echo "<p>hank you for your query.</p>";
else {
     echo "<p>Error: email failed."; die('Error!');
}
```

What has gone wrong with this code? Thank you in advance.

Have a good day and All the best,

Allison

Answer (score 0):

I see that you tried to stop the behaviour of submitted forms (with return false, which seems fine), I did this once too but don't now in which project that was, so I don't have any sample right now.

Maybe this helps (but didn't test it yet):

```
  $("#myForm").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var url = $(this).attr("action"); 
    var str=$(this).serialize();
    $.post(url,str,function(msg){$('msg_div').show();$('msg_div').html(msg);});
    return false;
  });
```

The `e.preventDefault();` should stop the submit process. How does your `validateForm()` look like?